# Change App's current CoreData source

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

For my application i'm using CoreData to store user's info and there might be multiple user accounts. So i need to create multiple CoreData files in different folders.

User logs out and app returns to login page. When they login with different account i need to create another CoreData source and change app's current CoreData source to new CoreData source.

[image: CoreData Source]

I have checked these but couldn't understand concept:

- [Refresh NSPersistentStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832438/refresh-nspersistentstorecoordinator-in-appdelegate-from-viewcontroller?rq=1)
- [Refferring NSPersistentStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074157/referring-to-nspersistentstore-instances-created-in-appdelegate)

What logic should i follow to accomplish this.

Thanks

Comment: why you are creating another `CoreData` source ? is there any specific requirement in your app? otherwise we can manage multiple user in single `CoreData` source with relationship.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I need to create another one because there might objects with same id for different accounts coming from server. And it will cause overwriting same object and my fetch request is based on id's. It will also ruin my fetch logic.

Comment: But that is also not possible that server have different different user with same id i don't think so please verify once with server guy may be its bug from services ?

Comment: Actually my app is email client. Consider that i connect to hotmail and fetched inbox of user "a" and after that user "a" logs out and logs in as user "b". Email id's start from 0 and goes up(based on email count). So definitely there will be same uids in different user mailboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Just base the core data store name on your user login and proceeded as normal.

So when the user logs out make sure you get rid of any NSManagedObjectContext, NSPersistentStoreCoordinator and NSPersistentStore. Then reinitialise them for the new user starting with the new store URL like this.

```
NSURL *store = [[self documentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_account.sqlite", userName]];
```